# Como poner una fecha especifica con el tipo de dato Date en Programacion orientada a Objetos

Tags: java, poo, java-8, programacion-asincrona, java-18

Buenas tardes me piden que con tipo de formato Date asigne la fecha de nacimiento de una persona quisiera saber como hacerlo, ya que poniendo la fecha directamente como la pongo en el codigo que les dejo abajo me salta error incluso si lo pongo sin comillas,  agradezco me puedan ayudar.

Clase persona:

```
package Class_Object;

public class People {
    /*
        Variables Nativas de la Clase
    */
    public String Name;
    public String lastName1;
    public String lastName2;
    public Date dataBrith;
    public float Heigth;
    
  
Clase Main:

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        People people1 = new People();
        people1.setName("Jaime");
        people1.lastName1 ="Hoyos";
        people1.lastName2="Madera";
        people1.dataBrith ="2000-08-04";
    }
    
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay varios APIS de fechas dentro de Java SE cada uno con tipos de datos distintos para fechas, te recomiendo especificar mejor que necesitas hacer con tus fechas para que obtengas una respuesta que sea ideal para tu caso

Comment: veo que tienes en el campo de la bd dateBirth y en la clase tienes como dateBrith. Talves ese sea el error.

Comment: Si es un ejercicio, recomendaría al profesor que actualizara el mismo: la clase java.util.Date debería usarse lo mínimo posible, el paquete java.time provee de una mejor implementación para tratar fechas, periodos, diferencias entre ellos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando `GregorianCalendar`

En tu caso:

```
people1.dataBrith = new GregorianCalendar(2000, Calendar.AUGUST, 4).getTime();
```

De todas formas yo consideraría usar `LocalDate` en lugar de `Date`. De esta forma sería:

```
people1.dataBrith =LocalDate.of( 2000, 8, 4);
```

y en tu clase `People`

```
public LocalDate dataBrith;
```

Answer (score 0):

hay varias formas de crear un objeto "Date", va mos con la más sencilla:

```
Date nacimiento = new Date( "2000-12-31" );
```

Para poder hacerlo de esta forma, tienes que pasarle la fecha en el formato **yyyy-MM-dd**, osea cuatro caracteres para el año, seguido de un guión, dos para el mes, otro guión y dos para el día.
Ahora bien, si quieres usar otro formato, por ejemplo "31/12/1999", debes usar lo siguiente:

```
String pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat( pattern );
```

Para crear un objeto Date:

```
Date dia = formatter.format( "31/12/1999 );
```

Y para pasar de Date a String:

```
String dia = formatter.format( dia );
```

Ahora bien, como te indicó @GavilanPatagonico, la clase Date esta desaconsejada para su uso, si es un ejercicio, no hay problema, pero debes saber que no es lo recomendable.
Espero que te sea de utilidad.